# Cast to string failed for value

Tags: javascript

При отправки формы высаккивает "ошибка 400", скриншот ошибки здесь
https://pastenow.ru/fd19fd27b433267dc843427f9381cbff

```
changeUserData(userName, userAbout) {
    return fetch (this._baseUrl + '/users/me', {
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: this._headers,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: userName,
        about: userAbout
      }),
    })
    .then(this._checkResponse);
  };

export default class PopupWithForm extends Popup {
  constructor (selectorPopup, selectorForm, handleFormSubmit) {
    super(selectorPopup);
    this._selectorForm = this._selectorPopup.querySelector(selectorForm)
    this._handleFormSubmit = handleFormSubmit;
  };
/* Получение значений из полей ввода */
  _getInputValues() {
    this._inputList = this._selectorPopup.querySelectorAll('.popup__input');
    this._newInputValues = {};
    this._inputList.forEach((inputElement) => {
      this._newInputValues[inputElement.name] = inputElement.value
    });
    return this._newInputValues
  };
/* Сброс значений полей ввода */
  resetForm() {
    this._selectorForm.reset();
  };
/* Добавление сброса формы в родительский метод закрытия модального окна*/
  closePopup() {
    super.closePopup(); 
    this.resetForm();
  };
/* Установка слушателей */
  setEventListeners() {
    super.setEventListeners();
    this._selectorForm.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
      evt.preventDefault();
      this._handleFormSubmit(this._getInputValues());
      this.closePopup();
    });
  }
};


/* ФОРМА ПРОФИЛЯ */  

/* Хендлер отправки формы */
const handleFormEditSubmit = (newInputValues) => {
  api.changeUserData(newInputValues)
    .then((userData) => {
    userInfo.setUserInfo(userData)
  })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

/* Открытие модального окана и подключение слушателей */
const popupEdit = new PopupWithForm(
  '.popup_type_edit', 
  '.popup__input-container_type_edit',
   handleFormEditSubmit
);

popupEdit.setEventListeners();

editprofileButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const userData = userInfo.getUserInfo();
  inputName.value = userData.name;
  inputAbout.value = userData.about;
  popupEdit.openPopup();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`changeUserData` принимает два параметра:

```
changeUserData(userName, userAbout) {
```

При вызове, передается всего один:

```
api.changeUserData(newInputValues)
```

В этом случае в первый параметр передается какой-то объект, который не могут привести к строке, о чем указано в начале ошибки, второй параметр остается пустым - о чем указано в конце ошибки.

Comment: а как правильно можно передать это двумя параметрами, если я в handleFormEditSubmit принмаю получается объект с двумя инпутами внутри?

Comment: @Default, передавай каждый инпут отдельным параметром. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ вообще ты как-то странно решил делать: сначала собираешь все в объект, потом ожидаешь отдельные параметры, чтобы потом перед отправкой опять собрать все в один объект

Comment: Я просто новичок так скажем и путаюсь как и что передавать, получается мне в саму функцию хендлера надо передать два параметра? Таким образом?
`
/* Хендлер отправки формы */
const handleFormEditSubmit = ({userName, userAbout}) => {
  api.changeUserData({userName, userAbout})
    .then((userData) => {
    userInfo.setUserInfo(userData)
  })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}; 
`
Если да, то ошибка осталась

Comment: как ту в комментариях код выделять? (

Comment: @Default, по повод [кода в комментариях](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3287/186999). По поводу твоего кода: обернув в фигурные скобки `({userName, userAbout})` - ты продолжаешь передавать объект. просто убери их и передадутся отдельные параметры

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, подтокнули в нужном направлении, сделал вот так и заработало
`const handleFormEditSubmit = (newInputValues) => {
  api.changeUserData(newInputValues['input-name'], newInputValues['input-about'])
    .then((userData) => {
    userInfo.setUserInfo(userData)
  })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};`